# colors on my page looks different they should do

Tags: html, colors

I'm just starting with html and I have a simple question. 
I'm trying to make a html template for mail and I've realized that, when I put a color as bg_color and I display the html page on my browser, the color is different from I expected.

I've read that colors looks different on different computers, on different OS or even different browser but I don't mean this... I mean that ,for example, in this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

If I put a color in the colors_picker, it looks different from the same color put as bg_color in my "page".

that makes any sense or I'm just stupid (?)

thank you all.

Comment: I would recommend using your browser's developer tools to check the CSS that is being used in your HTML. It could be that another style is overwriting what you think you've set.

Comment: Did you check this? https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email

Comment: mmmm I hadn't check it but I was using 6 Hex digits and bgcolor in <tg> as well. Emm... I think it isn't my browser CSS because I've tried it with differents browser ans looks the same way... actually color are the same as I defined but in other hue... maybe it's just my perception. I will ask somebody to read and mail with this template and wait for his/her answer. Thank you :)